# Disable Plugin if not logged in

Tags: plugins, mu-plugins

I am trying to disable a chatbot plugin if the user is not logged in.

In a MU Plugin I can use this filter - but the trouble is the is_user_logged_in() function does not yet exist, and neither is the global $current_user variable.

```
    add_filter('option_active_plugins', function( $plugins ){    
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) { 
            $chatBot = "chatbot/chatbot.php";
    
            $k = array_search( $chatBot, $plugins );
    
            if ($k !== false) {
                unset($plugins[$k]);
            }
        }

        return $plugins;
    } 
);
```

Is there another way to disable a plugin, if not logged in.

Comment: is this a plugin you've created yourself or a 3rd party plugin? I ask because this particular approach has major downsides, and it's usually much much easier to conditionally execute code in the plugin than it is to conditionally activate/deactivate a plugin like this. Likewise it's usually much easier and safer to unhook filters and actions than it is to conditionally deactivate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the author/maintainer of `chatbot/chatbot.php` then it's much easier to skip deactivating the plugin and put something like this at the top of the plugins PHP file:

```php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // remove_action, etc...
    return;
}
```

Similarly using `remove_action` or `remove_filter` is much safer. In your case it may be as simple as dequeuing the script/css assets of the plugin if the user is not logged in, or unhooking the function it uses to add them:

```php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // remove_action, etc...
}
```

This could be placed in a plugin or set up on the `init` hook in an MU plugin.

### When Should I Intercept To Disable Plugins?

You shouldn't!

In general, conditionally enabling and disabling a theme or plugin like this is an anti-pattern that will cause issues and have unintended consequences that will be difficult to work around that depend enormously on the plugin. Most of all, it's just not necessary to achieve the goal. It's highly unlikely your end goal is disabling the plugin, it's more likely to be a means to an end such as improving performance, not showing things to logged out users etc, which all have superior solutions without unexpected weirdness.

For example, if the code in your question worked, it would break all cron jobs for that plugin, and have other consequences elsewhere. Not all requests have a logged in state even if the user is logged in.

The only time you would do something like this is to force load plugins, either to always load them, or to load them based on server level variables such as `wp-config.php` constants or environment variables. E.g. force load the CDN plugin in production as it's required. But never based on user input/sessions/cookies/GET/POST, and to enable not disable things.

Comment: Thanks - I am not the author of the chatbot plugin. You raise some good points. I will have a re-think